# What is the meaning of command “:() { :|:& }; :” in shell?

Tags: linux, bash

I just encountered this command on a linux forum online where the author warned that donot try this command for curiosity. So my curiosity comes. What is the meaning of command “:() { :|:& }; :” in shell?

Comment: See [Fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) for that is what it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This fork bomb is described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-bash-fork-bomb/)

In bash, a function can be defined

```
function_name() { ... }
```

where `...` is the implementation or body of the function

```
:(){ ... }
```

defines a function named `:`.

```
:|:
```

runs the function within itself - that is recursively, and pipes it's output to another invocation of itself.

```
 &
```

runs the preceding command in the background.

So that gives us `:(){:|:&}` to define this function

```
 ;
```

separates the command defining the function from the following command on the same line (like `cd;pwd`)

```
 :
```

is a final command invocation which starts running the newly defined function.

---

Normally, I'd hope that per-user limits on processes or other resources would limit the effect of a fork bomb of this sort. Wikipedia has a description of [defusing a fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb#Defusing)

---

Addendum: After writing this answer I noticed this question was a duplicate of

- [What does this cryptic Bash command mean?](https://superuser.com/q/166755/52492)
- [Why this command crashes Linux](https://superuser.com/q/259883/52492)
- [What this command :(){ :|: & };: does?](https://superuser.com/q/625615/52492)

Other related questions

- [Does linux have any measures to protect against fork bombs?](https://superuser.com/questions/435690/does-linux-have-any-measures-to-protect-against-fork-bombs)
- [How to stop and detect the fork bomb](https://superuser.com/q/566958/52492)
- [Neutralize fork-bomb through ssh](https://superuser.com/q/478338/52492)

Comment: And also related [Why is whitespace sometimes needed around metacharacters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21186724/1983854) with a funny story around :)